declare the definition of a class separating from its body
Following code is in the same header file
#include <iostream>
               
class B
{
public:
    void doSth()
    {  
        A::func(1);
    } 
};

class A
{
public:
    static void func(int a)
    {
        std::cout<<"a = "<< a <<std::endl;
    }
};

If class A is defined after class B like above, the compiler will complain about ‘func’ is not a member 'A'.
My question is, is there anyway to solve this issue without changing the order how class B and class A are defined? Like putting a declaration of class A somewhere above class B? Thanks.

A warning about letting Sth do anything. Often ends in lightsaber duels, massive explosions, and crushing disappointment.

If you want B::doSth() to be declared and defined completely inside of B's class declaration, then you must move the full declaration of A ahead of B, eg:
#include <iostream>
               
class A
{
public:
    static void func(int a)
    {
        std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
    }
};  

class B
{
public:
    void doSth()
    {  
        A::func(1);
    } 
};

Otherwise, if you don't need B::doSth() to be completely inside the B class declaration then you can separate its declaration and definition, and then move the definition after the declaration of the A class, eg:
#include <iostream>
               
class B
{
public:
    void doSth();
};

class A
{
public:
    static void func(int a)
    {
        std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
    }
};

inline void B::doSth()
{  
    A::func(1);
} 

Preferably, method definitions that are not inside their class declaration should be implemented in separate .cpp files instead, eg:
A.h
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

class A
{
public:
    static void func(int a);
};

#endif

A.cpp
#include <iostream>               
#include "A.h"

void A::func(int a)
{
    std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
}

B.h
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

class B
{
public:
    void doSth();
};

#endif

B.cpp
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"
               
void B::doSth()
{  
    A::func(1);
} 


Just to note: If you leave the function definition in the header file but outside of the class definition, it should be marked inline (i.e. inline void B::doSth() { ... }).  Failing to do so will result in an ODR violation if the header is included in multiple translation units.

If you want B::doSth() to be defined inline, then you must move the declaration of A before B: This is not true. The requirement is the availability of the function definition in a translation unit, inline void doSth(); in the second code option will work.

@aschepler I rephrased my wording

You can't define a class separately from its "body", but you can define a class member function outside the class definition.
Like for example:
class A
{
public:
    static void func(int);
};

class B
{
public:
    void doSth()
    {
        A::func(1);
    }
};

void A::func(int a)
{
    /* Implementation of the function... */
}

You can of course define the B::doSth function outside as well, if the order of the class A and B definitions can't be changed.

Move member function definitions outside classes
#include <iostream>

class B {
 public:
  void doSth();
};

class A {
 public:
  static void func(int a) { std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl; }
  // Optional: static void func(int a);
};

void B::doSth() { A::func(1); }
// // static
// void A::func(int a) { std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl; }


Strange it should work, but in my actual code it complains about redefinition of doSth() at the bottom..... :(

Since this is a header file in the OP's question, should have an inline for the B::doSth definition so it has weak linkage.

If it's in a header, you need to use header guards and inline keyword.
